# Bouncycastle update from 1.46 to 1.56 not working

Tags: java, pgp

I have an existing PGP v 1.46 code in maintenance project. now I need to update to 1.56 and it's not working. a lot of classes and methods are changed. I have no idea about PGP.

Here is a sample demo of the exact code.

```
 plugins {
    id 'java'
}
group 'com.encryptor.pgp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/resources/libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcpg-jdk15on', version: '1.46'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-ext-jdk15on', version: '1.46'
    compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.46'
}
```

when i update from 1.46 to 1.56, it gives error.

processor

```
package com.encryptor.pgp;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
public class PGPFileProcessor {
    private String encryptFile;
    private String decryptFile;
    private String passphrase;
    private String publicKeyFile;
    private String privateKeyFile;
    private String plainTextFile;
    private boolean asciiArmored = false;
    private boolean integrityCheck = true;
    public PGPFileProcessor() {
    }
    public void setPublicKeyFile(String publicKeyFile) {
        this.publicKeyFile = publicKeyFile;
    }
    public void setPrivateKeyFile(String privateKeyFile) {
        this.privateKeyFile = privateKeyFile;
    }
    public void setEncryptFile(String encryptFile) {
        this.encryptFile = encryptFile;
    }
    public void setDecryptFile(String decryptFile) {
        this.decryptFile = decryptFile;
    }
    public void setPassphrase(String passphrase) {
        this.passphrase = passphrase;
    }
    public void setPlainTextFile(String plainTextFile) {
        this.plainTextFile = plainTextFile;
    }
    public void setAsciiArmored(boolean asciiArmored) {
        this.asciiArmored = asciiArmored;
    }
    public void setIntegrityCheck(boolean integrityCheck) {
        this.integrityCheck = integrityCheck;
    }
    public boolean encrypt() throws Exception {
        FileInputStream keyIn = new FileInputStream(publicKeyFile);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(encryptFile, true);
        PGPUtil.encryptFile(out, plainTextFile, PGPUtil.readPublicKey(keyIn), asciiArmored, integrityCheck);
        out.close();
        keyIn.close();
        return true;
    }
    public boolean decrypt() throws Exception {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(encryptFile);
        FileInputStream keyIn = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(decryptFile);
        PGPUtil.decryptFile(in, out, keyIn, passphrase.toCharArray());
        in.close();
        out.close();
        keyIn.close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
package com.encryptor.pgp;    
public class PGPMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PGPFileProcessor pgpFileProcessor = new PGPFileProcessor();
        pgpFileProcessor.setEncryptFile("enc.txt"); pgpFileProcessor.setDecryptFile("dec.txt");
        pgpFileProcessor.setPassphrase("pgpencr");
        pgpFileProcessor.setInputFile("plain.txt");
        private boolean asciiArmored = false;
        pgpFileProcessor.setPublicKeyFile("publickey.key");
        pgpFileProcessor.setPrivateKeyFile("pivatekey.key");
        pgpFileProcessor.encrypt();*/
        pgpFileProcessor.encrypt();
        pgpFileProcessor.decrypt();
    }
}
```

Util

```
package com.encryptor.pgp;
    import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredOutputStream;
    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
    import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.*;    
    import java.io.*;
    import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.security.Security;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    public class PGPUtil {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static PGPPublicKey readPublicKey(InputStream in) throws IOException, PGPException {
            in = org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);
            PGPPublicKeyRingCollection pgpPub = new PGPPublicKeyRingCollection(in);/* we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for encryption, in the real world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this. */
            PGPPublicKey key = null;/* iterate through the key rings. */
            Iterator<PGPPublicKeyRing> rIt = pgpPub.getKeyRings();
            while (key == null && rIt.hasNext()) {
                PGPPublicKeyRing kRing = rIt.next();
                Iterator<PGPPublicKey> kIt = kRing.getPublicKeys();
                while (key == null && kIt.hasNext()) {
                    PGPPublicKey k = kIt.next();
                    if (k.isEncryptionKey()) key = k;
                }
            }
            if (key == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't find encryption key in key ring.");
            return key;
        }
        private static PGPPrivateKey findSecretKey(InputStream keyIn, long keyID, char[] pass) throws IOException, PGPException, NoSuchProviderException {
            PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn));
            PGPSecretKey pgpSecKey = pgpSec.getSecretKey(keyID);
            if (pgpSecKey == null) return null;
            return pgpSecKey.extractPrivateKey(pass, "BC");
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public static void decryptFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out, InputStream keyIn, char[] passwd) throws Exception {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            in = org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);
            PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
            PGPEncryptedDataList enc;
            Object o = pgpF.nextObject();/* the first object might be a PGP marker packet. */
            if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
            else enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();/* find the secret key */
            Iterator<PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData> it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
            PGPPrivateKey sKey = null;
            PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
            while (sKey == null && it.hasNext()) {
                pbe = it.next();
                sKey = findSecretKey(keyIn, pbe.getKeyID(), passwd);
            }
            if (sKey == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Secret key for message not found.");
            InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(sKey, "BC");
            PGPObjectFactory plainFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);
            Object message = plainFact.nextObject();
            if (message instanceof PGPCompressedData) {
                PGPCompressedData cData = (PGPCompressedData) message;
                PGPObjectFactory pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData.getDataStream());
                message = pgpFact.nextObject();
            }
            if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData) {
                PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData) message;
                InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
                int ch;
                while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0) out.write(ch);
            } else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList)
                throw new PGPException("Encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
            else throw new PGPException("Message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
            if (pbe.isIntegrityProtected() && !pbe.verify()) throw new PGPException("Message failed integrity check");
        }
        public static void encryptFile(OutputStream out, String fileName, PGPPublicKey encKey, boolean armor, boolean withIntegrityCheck) throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException, PGPException {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            if (armor) out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PGPCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(PGPCompressedData.ZIP);
            org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.writeFileToLiteralData(comData.open(bOut), PGPLiteralData.BINARY, new File(fileName));
            comData.close();
            PGPEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(PGPEncryptedData.CAST5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom(), "BC");
            cPk.addMethod(encKey);
            byte[] bytes = bOut.toByteArray();
            OutputStream cOut = cPk.open(out, bytes.length);
            cOut.write(bytes);
            cOut.close();
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like as that your "old" PGP encryption methods were taken from a Bouncy Castle example, so I used the renewed Bouncy Castle examples in https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples for a simple test.

You wrote that the problem shows up when updating Bouncy Castle to version **1.56** - this is outdated as well and the actual version is **1.65** and my example works with this version (and OpenJDK 11.0.6). Take my files as a working basis for your maintenance.

First you need a PGP keypair - for my example I generated one with 'RSAKeyPairGenerator.java -a myidentity mypassphrase' to get the files 'secret.asc' (private key) and 'pub.asc' (public key).

For PGP file encryption you need two more files - 'KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor.java' and 'PGPExampleUtil.java.' In class 'KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor.java' I changed the constructor of the methods decryptFile and encryptFile from 'private' to 'public' to get access from the PGPMain.java.

It's just one line of code for pgp file encryption and another line for pgp file decryption. As the original filename can get stored within the encrypted file
I added a "rename-method" to change the original filename 'plain.txt' to 'plain_org.txt'. **Be aware that the decryptFile-method will overwrite an existing file without warning or notice and there is no propper exception handling.**

The complete set of files including Bouncy Castle library is available here: https://github.com/java-crypto/Stackoverflow/tree/master/PGP_Encryption_after_Update_Not_Working. You need the bcprov-jdk15to18-165.jar and bcpg-jdk15on-165.jar!

PGPMain.java:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.Security;

public class PGPMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchProviderException, IOException, PGPException {
        System.out.println("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927913/bouncycastle-update-from-1-46-to-1-56-not-working");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); // get bouncy castle: https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html
        System.out.println("\nJava version: " + Runtime.version() + " BouncyCastle Version: " + Security.getProvider("BC"));
        // create a keypair with RSAKeyPairGenerator.java

        // encryption
        KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor.encryptFile("enc.txt", "plain.txt", "pub.asc", false, true);

        // rename plaintextfile as it will be overwritten by decryptFile (filename is stored within encrypted file)
        File file = new File("plain.txt");
        file.renameTo(new File("plain_org.txt"));

        // decryption will generate the decrypted file with original filename !
        KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor.decryptFile("enc.txt", "secret.asc", "mypassphrase".toCharArray(), "defaultfilename.txt");
        // return the original filename, to change this behavior change the code in class KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor lines 142-146
    }
}
```

KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor.java

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.bouncycastle.bcpg.ArmoredOutputStream;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPCompressedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPEncryptedDataList;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPLiteralData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPOnePassSignatureList;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPrivateKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKeyRingCollection;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.jcajce.JcaPGPObjectFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.Streams;

/**
 * A simple utility class that encrypts/decrypts public key based
 * encryption large files.
 * <p>
 * To encrypt a file: KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor -e [-a|-ai] fileName publicKeyFile.<br>
 * If -a is specified the output file will be "ascii-armored".
 * If -i is specified the output file will be have integrity checking added.
 * <p>
 * To decrypt: KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor -d fileName secretKeyFile passPhrase.
 * <p>
 * Note 1: this example will silently overwrite files, nor does it pay any attention to
 * the specification of "_CONSOLE" in the filename. It also expects that a single pass phrase
 * will have been used.
 * <p>
 * Note 2: this example generates partial packets to encode the file, the output it generates
 * will not be readable by older PGP products or products that don't support partial packet
 * encoding.
 * <p>
 * Note 3: if an empty file name has been specified in the literal data object contained in the
 * encrypted packet a file with the name filename.out will be generated in the current working directory.
 */
public class KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor
{ // source: https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor.java
    // changed from private to public
    public static void decryptFile(
            String inputFileName,
            String keyFileName,
            char[] passwd,
            String defaultFileName)
            throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException
    {
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFileName));
        InputStream keyIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(keyFileName));
        decryptFile(in, keyIn, passwd, defaultFileName);
        keyIn.close();
        in.close();
    }

    /**
     * decrypt the passed in message stream
     */
    private static void decryptFile(
            InputStream in,
            InputStream keyIn,
            char[]      passwd,
            String      defaultFileName)
            throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException
    {
        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

        try
        {
            JcaPGPObjectFactory        pgpF = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(in);
            PGPEncryptedDataList    enc;

            Object                  o = pgpF.nextObject();
            //
            // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
            //
            if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList)
            {
                enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList)o;
            }
            else
            {
                enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList)pgpF.nextObject();
            }

            //
            // find the secret key
            //
            Iterator                    it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
            PGPPrivateKey               sKey = null;
            PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData   pbe = null;
            PGPSecretKeyRingCollection  pgpSec = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(
                    PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(keyIn), new JcaKeyFingerprintCalculator());

            while (sKey == null && it.hasNext())
            {
                pbe = (PGPPublicKeyEncryptedData)it.next();

                sKey = PGPExampleUtil.findSecretKey(pgpSec, pbe.getKeyID(), passwd);
            }

            if (sKey == null)
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("secret key for message not found.");
            }

            InputStream         clear = pbe.getDataStream(new JcePublicKeyDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(sKey));

            JcaPGPObjectFactory    plainFact = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(clear);

            PGPCompressedData   cData = (PGPCompressedData)plainFact.nextObject();

            InputStream         compressedStream = new BufferedInputStream(cData.getDataStream());
            JcaPGPObjectFactory    pgpFact = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(compressedStream);

            Object              message = pgpFact.nextObject();

            if (message instanceof PGPLiteralData)
            {
                PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData)message;

                String outFileName = ld.getFileName();
                if (outFileName.length() == 0)
                {
                    outFileName = defaultFileName;
                }

                InputStream unc = ld.getInputStream();
                OutputStream fOut =  new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFileName));

                Streams.pipeAll(unc, fOut);

                fOut.close();
            }
            else if (message instanceof PGPOnePassSignatureList)
            {
                throw new PGPException("encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new PGPException("message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");
            }

            if (pbe.isIntegrityProtected())
            {
                if (!pbe.verify())
                {
                    System.err.println("message failed integrity check");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.err.println("message integrity check passed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("no message integrity check");
            }
        }
        catch (PGPException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            if (e.getUnderlyingException() != null)
            {
                e.getUnderlyingException().printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    // changed from private to public
    public static void encryptFile(
            String          outputFileName,
            String          inputFileName,
            String          encKeyFileName,
            boolean         armor,
            boolean         withIntegrityCheck)
            throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException, PGPException
    {
        OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFileName));
        PGPPublicKey encKey = PGPExampleUtil.readPublicKey(encKeyFileName);
        encryptFile(out, inputFileName, encKey, armor, withIntegrityCheck);
        out.close();
    }

    private static void encryptFile(
            OutputStream    out,
            String          fileName,
            PGPPublicKey    encKey,
            boolean         armor,
            boolean         withIntegrityCheck)
            throws IOException, NoSuchProviderException
    {
        if (armor)
        {
            out = new ArmoredOutputStream(out);
        }

        try
        {
            PGPEncryptedDataGenerator   cPk = new PGPEncryptedDataGenerator(new JcePGPDataEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.CAST5).setWithIntegrityPacket(withIntegrityCheck).setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom()).setProvider("BC"));

            cPk.addMethod(new JcePublicKeyKeyEncryptionMethodGenerator(encKey).setProvider("BC"));

            OutputStream                cOut = cPk.open(out, new byte[1 << 16]);

            PGPCompressedDataGenerator  comData = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(
                    PGPCompressedData.ZIP);

            PGPUtil.writeFileToLiteralData(comData.open(cOut), PGPLiteralData.BINARY, new File(fileName), new byte[1 << 16]);

            comData.close();

            cOut.close();

            if (armor)
            {
                out.close();
            }
        }
        catch (PGPException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e);
            if (e.getUnderlyingException() != null)
            {
                e.getUnderlyingException().printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(
            String[] args)
            throws Exception
    {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        if (args.length == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("usage: KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor -e|-d [-a|ai] file [secretKeyFile passPhrase|pubKeyFile]");
            return;
        }

        if (args[0].equals("-e"))
        {
            if (args[1].equals("-a") || args[1].equals("-ai") || args[1].equals("-ia"))
            {
                encryptFile(args[2] + ".asc", args[2], args[3], true, (args[1].indexOf('i') > 0));
            }
            else if (args[1].equals("-i"))
            {
                encryptFile(args[2] + ".bpg", args[2], args[3], false, true);
            }
            else
            {
                encryptFile(args[1] + ".bpg", args[1], args[2], false, false);
            }
        }
        else if (args[0].equals("-d"))
        {
            decryptFile(args[1], args[2], args[3].toCharArray(), new File(args[1]).getName() + ".out");
        }
        else
        {
            System.err.println("usage: KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor -d|-e [-a|ai] file [secretKeyFile passPhrase|pubKeyFile]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, michael, just 1 issue, your code is encrypting file perfectly, reading data from plain.txt, create enc.txt with encrypted data and rename plain.txt to plain_org.txt, but at the time of decryption, it's not creating any new file. I believe as per your code, the decrypted file must be defaultfilename.txt, but it's not generating any file of this name.

Comment: funny :-) In PGPMain I commented out the lines ' KeyBasedLargeFileProcessor.encryptFile...' and 'file.renameTo...' and left only the 'enc.txt' and 'secret.asc' files in the path and after decryption there is a file 'plain.txt' and the message 'message integrity check passed' on concole, so decryption seems to work as expected. The 'defaultfilename.txt' is used when no original filename was stored in the encrypted file. I recommend that you're doing the encryption and decryption in two separate steps and manually delete the plaintext-file, that way you will see that a new file is created.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you need 2 Bouncy Castle files to get this to work: you need the bcprov-jdk15to18-165.jar and bcpg-jdk15on-165.jar...